# how to ban a facebook user from a facebook application, through api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We are having a facebook App we have detected some abusive users so we want to stop them from logging into our app, Any thoughts? There are examples given but Fb docs say those api's are deprecated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just detect them on your own and set a flag in your database. They will still be able to use Facebook Login, but they will not be able to do anything in your App if they are flagged.

Either way, i did some Google research and found out that it may be possible with a simple POST (or DELETE) request to the `/app-id/banned` endpoint:

**BAN**

https://graph.facebook.com/{app-id}/banned

POST parameters:

- `access_token` (A simple App Access Token)
- `uid` (comma separated list of user IDs)

**UNBAN**

https://graph.facebook.com/{app-id}/banned/{user-id}

DELETE request, only `access_token` as parameter

---

It is not really documented though, but easy to test.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/banned/ --->according to this, we can get a list of banned users so the questions is how to ban them

Comment: I will test this and let you know

Comment: perfect Thanks a lot